Does every degeneracy come from symmetries in QM?
In my university, my professor said that every degeneracy in QM comes from a symmetry of the Hamiltonian. But I'm not sure it is true for all the cases.
My counter-example is as follows:
In the 3D harmonic oscillator, $E_n=\hbar\omega(n+m+l+3/2)$, where $(n,m,l)$ are quantum numbers of $x,y,z$ oscillator.
For $E_n=\hbar\omega(5+3/2)$, there exists possible $(n,m,l)$ like $(1,1,3), (1,3,1), (3,1,1)$. It seems like these 3 degeneracies come from rotational symmetry. However, can we find any symmetry between 2 degeneracies $(1,1,3)$ and $(0,0,5)$?

The 3D isotropic QHO can be solved in spherical harmonics basis, and then you can read off the symmetries directly. When you do that, you will realise that your example is a failure. I actually agree with your premise; that there can be accidental degeneracies that do not come from some symmetry, but that ought to require some contrived example, not something as simple as what you are thinking of.

A place to look for accidental degeneracy may be in the band structures of solids, whenever two bands cross outside of a high symmetry point

Conceptually, accidental degeneracy is not too uncommon.  For example, a two-band  non-interacting Hamiltonian that depends on spatial momentum (2 real eigenvalues but 3 real $\vec{k}$ parameters) generally have band crossings.  The thing is, without any symmetry protection, any perturbation (due to interaction, impurity, external environment, etc.) will lift the degeneracy.

A simple Google search gave this old article: Haruo Ui, Gyo Takeda, Does Accidental Degeneracy Imply a Symmetry Group? Progress of Theoretical Physics, Volume 72, Issue 2, August 1984, Pages 266–284
The argument in the article proves that there is no maximal symmetry group in their case; In fact, they have found a particular case whereby the degeneracy is not mapped by any symmetry operator. Instead, they found a structure that gets it to work.
Now, do you consider this a symmetry or not? What would be the most general definition of a symmetry in quantum theory?
Maybe you can find an even better counter-example, but this paper is already very informative.
